# base64 encoding for utf-8 strings

Tags: delphi, encoding, utf-8

i have rad studio xe5
i used indy EncodeString for encoding the input string...

my code is like this:

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  UTF8: UTF8String;
begin
UTF8 := UTF8Encode(m1.Text);
m2.Text := ind.EncodeString(UTF8);
end;
```

but the output is wrong for utf-8 inputs

```
orange  --> b3Jhbmdl  [correct]
book   --> Ym9vaw==   [correct]
سلام  -->  Pz8/Pw==   [wrong]
کتاب  --> Pz8/Pw==   [wrong]
دلفی  --> Pz8/Pw==   [wrong]
```

for utf-8 for all inputs it returned same out put!!!
what is wrong with my code and how can i have a good result of base64 encoding with utf-8 strings

Comment: Are you using Indy for other than base64?

Comment: im using indy and problem fixed, just read the accepted answer

Comment: My point is that people often use Indy just for base64, and there is a cleaner way to get base64 than using Indy. Of course, if you are using Indy, then its base64 code is a good call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like @RRUZ said, `EncodeString()` expects you to specify a byte encoding that the input `String` will be converted to, and then those octets will be encoded to base64.

You are passing a `UTF8String` to `EncodeString()`, which takes a `UnicodeString` as input in XE5, so the RTL will convert the `UTF8String` data back to UTF-16, undoing your `UTF8Encode()` (which is deprecated, BTW).  Since you are not specifying a byte encoding, Indy uses its default encoding, which is set to ASCII by default (configurable via the `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit).

That is why `orange` works (no data loss) but `سلام` fails (data loss).

You need to get rid of your `UTF8String` altogether, and let Indy handle the UTF-8 for you:

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m2.Text := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(m1.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
end;
```

`DecodeString()` has a similar parameter for specifying the byte encoding of the octets that have been base64 encoded.  The input is first decoded to bytes, and then the bytes are converted to `UnicodeString` using the specified byte encoding, eg:

```
procedure TForm5.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m1.Text := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString(m2.Text, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

You must call the `EncodeString` method passing a proper byte encoding class.

Try this

```
m2.Text := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(UTF8, IndyUTF8Encoding);
```

(IndyUTF8Encoding is defined in the `IdGlobal`unit)

Comment: DON'T assign the source `String` to a `UTF8String` first. Pass it as-is to `EncodeString()` and let Indy convert the `String` to UTF-8 internally before it then encodes the octets to base64: `m2.Text := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(m1.Text, IndyUTF8Encoding);`.  If you are using D2007 or earlier, `EncodeString()` take an additional parameter that lets you specify the Ansi encoding of the `String` so `EncodeString()` can convert it to UTF-8 correctly. Also FYI, `IndyUTF8Encoding` has been replaced with `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` in Indy 10.6.

Answer (score 2):

For RadStudio10 C++

`#include <IdGlobal.hpp> 
String my_str = L"Շնորհակալություն";
String str = IdEncoderMIME1->EncodeString(my_str ,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8());
my_str = IdDecoderMIME1->DecodeString(str ,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8());`